# Reclassifying 1 band TIFF with gdal_calc

Tags: gdal-calc

I have a single band 8 bit TIFF and want to reclassify the following cell values to 1 as follows:

```
 OLD   NEW
 26     1
 71     1
 20     1
 24     1
```

I have tried the following which as far as I can understand translates the Band-A values.

```
gdal_calc -A input.tif --outfile=output_reclass.tif --calc="(A==26)+(A==71)+(A==20)+(A==24)*1" --overwrite
```

The result is always an empty TIFF.

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: The expression seems correct. make sure you are using the correct input file. Alternatively  use `gdal_calc` expression as it appears in *QGIS's GDAL Raster Calculator* `--overwrite --calc "(A==26)+(A==71)+(A==20)+(A==24)*1" --format GTiff --type Int32 -A D:/Practice/Python/Main/A.tif --A_band 1 --outfile D:/Practice/Python/Main/gdal_calc_output2.tif`

Comment: have you tried specifying the band specifically with `--A_band=1` ?